# R/apcluster and skilearn

Tags: python, r

I have been involved in analysis using a software called `depict` which includes affinity propagation analysis in Python.

I am keen to implement a counterpart using `R/apcluster` for additional analysis. It seems both use correlation but the results are slightly different. Is that possible to get to the bottom of this? Thanks very much.

```
af_obj = AffinityPropagation(affinity = 'precomputed', max_iter=10000, convergence_iter=1000) # using almost only default parameters

print "Affinity Propagation parameters:"

for param, val in af_obj.get_params().items():

    print "\t{}: {}".format(param, val)

    print "Perfoming Affinity Propagation.."

af = af_obj.fit(matrix_corr)
```

as in Python: https://github.com/jinghuazhao/PW-pipeline/blob/master/files/network_plot.py

```
require(apcluster)

apres <- apcluster(corSimMat,tRaw,details=TRUE)
```

as in R:
https://github.com/jinghuazhao/PW-pipeline/blob/master/files/network.R
J

Jing hua

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to have all functionality of the R package `apcluster` available in Python!

To answer your questions regarding different results:

1. First of all, check whether the correlation/similarity matrixes are the same.
2. Also note that the results are not 100% deterministic, since a small amount of random noise is added internally.
3. You would have to check all parameters of the two implementations if they are all the same. Obviously, you do not get the same results for both implementations if you use default parameters. But this is only an issue if the defaults are exactly the same. As far as I know, they are not. The default damping parameter, for instance, is not the same.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks -- it looks I still have homework to do. A related question, how do you recommend select number of clumbers K for cutree?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at the dendrogram and choose the K where the "longest legs". Take a loot at the examples in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apcluster/vignettes/apcluster.pdf. On p. 21, this would be 2. On p. 37, this is not so clear, but probably 5 (or 3).

Comment: Thank you! I will look at a bit more of these.